# use QR for login in to application

Tags: kotlin, authentication

I want the user to log in to the program after scanning his own QR code, please guide me
and show user profile in many TextView At Next Activity ?

fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

```
        val result  = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (result.equals(123456)) {

            //Activity.RESULT_OK

            var i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
            Toast.makeText(this, "WELCOME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
        if (requestCode != 123456)
            Toast.makeText(this, "USER NOT FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }


    }
```